# JavaScript freezing/crashing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, web-worker

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36mdt/

After about 10-20 seconds, the display starts to freeze randomly and shortly after crashes. I cannot reproduce this in Firefox.

Profiling reveals nothing unusual.

http://jsfiddle.net/3pbdQ/ shows there is definitely a memory leak. Even a 1 FPS, the memory usage climes 5 megabytes a frame.

On a side note, this example really shows how Math.random() is really not so random.

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but that visual effect is freaking AWESOME... :)

Comment: Did you notice that after 10 seconds, it's using `1.2GB` of memory

Comment: @Esailija The task manager shows that, but profiling shows no change...?

Comment: @MathWizz what do you mean by profiling

Comment: @Esailija The "Profiles" tab in the Chrome console.

Comment: @MathWizz be more specific, if you mean heap snapshots, they're just for javascript in the current tab. The whole memory usage shoots up to `1gb` really fast.

Comment: @Esailija Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: You should be looking at the Timeline, which will show live memory usage.

Comment: I used the Chrome timeline to record memory in the current tab and it didn't show anything unusual - could it be because JSFiddle executes results in an iframe, which isn't included in the Chrome profiler stats?

Comment: @Tyrsius Wow! I've never noticed that before. I'll definitely be using it.

Comment: Filed a Chrome bug: http://crbug.com/132769

Comment: Maybe because chrome stacks all your `setInterval(update, fps/1000)` witch is one every `fps/1000` => `30/1000` = `0.03 sec`. You'll have to reverse fps and 1000: setInterval(update, 1000/fps);

Comment: I have no setIntervals. They are all setTimeouts. I tried changing it to setInterval, but there is no change. http://jsfiddle.net/6URcC/

Comment: @MathWizz. Sorry i meant setTimeout. But you'll have to change the calculation form fps/1000 to 1000/fps.

Comment: @MathWizz there is a great improvement if you calculate the array length OUTSIDE each iteration condition. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done only 2 performance improvements and it doesn't crash after 5 mins (also seems to be not leaking memory). Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/3pbdQ/3/

1. Don't calculate the size inside each iteration
2. Use timeouts instead of freezing interval.
3. Use bitwise operator for flooring a number

> **Profiling reveals nothing unusual.**

Chrome Profiler doesn't work with WebWorkers, AFAIK. As per conversation with Paul Irish:

> "Check about:inspect for shared workers, also you can do console.profile() within the worker code (I THINK) and capture those bits. The "cleans up" is the garbage collector: if after the cleanup there is still a growing line of excess memory, then thats a leak."

And

> **On a side note, this example really shows how Math.random() is really
>   not so random.**

It is well known there are no perfect random algorithms, but anyway the bunch of grouped colors you see is because you're not setting canvas.height and canvas.width, and it differs from CSS values.

**EDIT**: Still leaking memory, I don't know why, about after 10 secs it 'cleans up'. Exceeds my knowledge, but works smoothly at 60 FPS (`var TIME = 16`)

Comment: It still has a memory leak if you let it sit for half an hour.

Comment: @MathWizz yup, I realized that as per my last edit, but exceeds my knowledge about how to "clean it" correctly, besides the garbage collector.

Comment: Accepting because it helps the memory leak at lot, even though it does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the system and browser version you use some steps may vary although I tried my best to provide common steps that are compatible with most systems.

Disable Sandbox:
1. Right click Google Chrome desktop icon.
2. Select Properties.
3. Click Shortcut > Target.
4. Add "--no-sandbox"
5. Click Apply | OK.
6. Download and install ZombieSoftFix.
7. Check and resolve conflicts detected.

Disable Plug-Ins:
1. Type "about:plugins" in Address Bar.
2. Press ENTER.
3. Disable all plug-ins displayed in the list page.

Clear Temporary Files:
1. Click Wrench.
2. Select More Tools | Clear browsing data.
3. Check-up all boxes, click "Clear browsing data" button to confirm the process.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate, known [Chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68190).

Comment: Interesting... It has been fixed recently though: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132769#c7 :D